# Unused variable in Python

Tags: python

This is my first time to create a python program to take screenshot every two seconds. The problem is that I don't know how to break the while loop. I wrote while sscount is not zero, keep screenshotting. Then when a user press ESC button, set sscount to 0. This should stop the while loop but I get the warning, "Unused variable 'sscount'" and it doesn't stop the while loop either.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

```
import pynput
import pyautogui
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0

    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            sscount = 0 #this is where the warning comes.
            return False

    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

    while sscount != 0:
        pyautogui.screenshot('/users/aliha/desktop/screenshot/image'+str(sscount)+'.png')
        sscount += 1
        time.sleep(2.0)
```

Comment: You have to use a global variable `sscount`, and declare it as `global` in `on_release` - otherwise each time a new local variable is created and discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to use variable `sscount` globally and  to manipulate the global variable within function `on_release` , you have to declare sscount as global variable in the function using `global sscount`. Complete result:

```
def on_release(key):
    global sscount
    if key == Key.esc:
        sscount = 0 #this is where the warning comes.
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Below a snippet code to enhance.

- The main program run while `is_running` is `True`
- `ctrl+c` event set `is_running` to `False`
- screenshot is took if the elasped time is upper than 2 sec between 2 `<escape>` key pressed
- output path is not hardcoded
- global variable is used to share state

```py
import time
from os.path import expanduser
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller


keyboard = Controller()
is_running = True
sscount = 0
previous_date = None
screenshot_dir = None

def on_press(key: Key):
    global previous_date, sscount
    have_to_take_screenshot = False
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if previous_date is None:
        previous_date = current_date
        have_to_take_screenshot = True
    else:
        elapsed_time = current_date - previous_date
        if elapsed_time > datetime.timedelta(seconds=2):
            previous_date = current_date
            have_to_take_screenshot = True
        else:
            have_to_take_screenshot = False

    print(have_to_take_screenshot)
    if have_to_take_screenshot and key == Key.esc:
        pyautogui.screenshot(f'{screenshot_dir}/image{sscount}.png')
        sscount+= 1


def on_release(key: Key):
    global screenshot_dir
    should_continue = True
    print(key)
    if key == Key.esc:
        is_running = False
        should_continue = False
    return should_continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    home_dir = expanduser('~/')
    screenshot_dir = Path(f'{home_dir}/desktop/screenshot')

    if not screenshot_dir.exists():
        screenshot_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    while is_running:
        try:
            with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
                listener.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            is_running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to raise a `StopIteration` and make the loop infinite.

```
import pynput
import pyautogui
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            raise StopIteration

    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

    while True:
        pyautogui.screenshot('/users/aliha/desktop/screenshot/image'+str(sscount)+'.png')
        time.sleep(2.0)
```